# Print a particular object from json in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I print only the text from the json. I am working on ruby on rails app.

```
    tweets = JSON.parse(response.body)
    tweets.each do |tweet|
          "#{tweet["text"]}"
    end
```

I tried the above code bt it displays the whole json.

Response.body :

> [{"created_at"=>"Mon Jun 09 02:49:17 +0000 2014",
>   "id"=>475831972812423168, "id_str"=>"475831972812423168",
>   "text"=>"@debalec #DIST1", "source"=>"https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tfw\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for
>   Websites", "truncated"=>false, "in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil,
>   "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil, "in_reply_to_user_id"=>2551123651,
>   "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>"2551123651",
>   "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>"debalec", "user"=>{"id"=>1551421092,
>   "id_str"=>"1551421092", "name"=>"The Third",
>   "screen_name"=>"thethird", "location"=>"", "description"=>"",
>   "url"=>nil, "entities"=>{"description"=>{"urls"=>[]}},
>   "protected"=>false, "followers_count"=>12, "friends_count"=>199,
>   "listed_count"=>0, "created_at"=>"Thu Jun 27 20:24:56 +0000 2013",
>   "favourites_count"=>54, "utc_offset"=>nil, "time_zone"=>nil,
>   "geo_enabled"=>false, "verified"=>false, "statuses_count"=>82,
>   "lang"=>"en", "contributors_enabled"=>false, "is_translator"=>false,
>   "is_translation_enabled"=>false, "profile_background_color"=>"59BEE4",
>   "profile_background_image_url"=>"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000083038715/7b1cad0896d22d75b85f5f86fc69b59f.jpeg",
>   "profile_background_image_url_https"=>"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000083038715/7b1cad0896d22d75b85f5f86fc69b59f.jpeg",
>   "profile_background_tile"=>false,
>   "profile_image_url"=>"http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4_normal.png",
>   "profile_image_url_https"=>"https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4_normal.png",
>   "profile_link_color"=>"8FCAE0",
>   "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"4BB7DF",
>   "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"191F22",
>   "profile_text_color"=>"4BB7DF", "profile_use_background_image"=>true,
>   "default_profile"=>false, "default_profile_image"=>true,
>   "following"=>false, "follow_request_sent"=>false,
>   "notifications"=>false}, "geo"=>nil, "coordinates"=>nil, "place"=>nil,
>   "contributors"=>nil, "retweet_count"=>0, "favorite_count"=>0,
>   "entities"=>{"hashtags"=>[{"text"=>"DIST1", "indices"=>[10, 16]}],
>   "symbols"=>[], "urls"=>[],
>   "user_mentions"=>[{"screen_name"=>"debalec", "name"=>"DebaElec",
>   "id"=>2551123651, "id_str"=>"2551123651", "indices"=>[0, 8]}]},
>   "favorited"=>false, "retweeted"=>false, "lang"=>"und"},
>   {"created_at"=>"Fri Jun 06 22:41:39 +0000 2014",
>   "id"=>475044876841938944, "id_str"=>"475044876841938944", "text"=>"hi
>   @debalec", "source"=>"http://twitter.com/download/android\"
>   rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android", "truncated"=>false,
>   "in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil, "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil,
>   "in_reply_to_user_id"=>nil, "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>nil,
>   "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>nil, "user"=>{"id"=>1551421092,
>   "id_str"=>"1551421092", "name"=>"the third",
>   "screen_name"=>"the third", "location"=>"", "description"=>"",
>   "url"=>nil, "entities"=>{"description"=>{"urls"=>[]}},
>   "protected"=>false, "followers_count"=>12, "friends_count"=>199,
>   "listed_count"=>0, "created_at"=>"Thu Jun 27 20:24:56 +0000 2013",
>   "favourites_count"=>54, "utc_offset"=>nil, "time_zone"=>nil,
>   "geo_enabled"=>false, "verified"=>false, "statuses_count"=>82,
>   "lang"=>"en", "contributors_enabled"=>false, "is_translator"=>false,
>   "is_translation_enabled"=>false, "profile_background_color"=>"59BEE4",
>   "profile_background_image_url"=>"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000083038715/7b1cad0896d22d75b85f5f86fc69b59f.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https"=>"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000083038715/7b1cad0896d22d75b85f5f86fc69b59f.jpeg",
>   "profile_background_tile"=>false,"profile_image_url"=>"http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4_normal.png","profile_image_url_https"=>"https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4_normal.png",
>   "profile_link_color"=>"8FCAE0",
>   "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"4BB7DF",
>   "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"191F22",
>   "profile_text_color"=>"4BB7DF", "profile_use_background_image"=>true,
>   "default_profile"=>false, "default_profile_image"=>true,
>   "following"=>false, "follow_request_sent"=>false,
>   "notifications"=>false}, "geo"=>nil, "coordinates"=>nil, "place"=>nil,
>   "contributors"=>nil, "retweet_count"=>0, "favorite_count"=>0,
>   "entities"=>{"hashtags"=>[], "symbols"=>[], "urls"=>[],
>   "user_mentions"=>[{"screen_name"=>"debalec", "name"=>"DebaElec",
>   "id"=>2551123651, "id_str"=>"2551123651", "indices"=>[3, 11]}]},
>   "favorited"=>false, "retweeted"=>false, "lang"=>"und"}]

Comment: Please paste response.body

Comment: where exactly you are trying to print the results ? means in erb file or some where else ?

Comment: @SagarBommidi yes I am trying to print on the erb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `each`:

```
tweets = JSON.parse(response.body)
tweets.map do |tweet|
  tweet["text"]
end
```

And there is no need to interpolate `tweet["text"]`.

Answer (score 0):

One problem here is that you're using quotes within quotes. Forgot to escape?

Another issue is that you're not printing anything. Merely returning the text in a loop does nothing and would always return the `tweets` object when the loop is complete.

So, here you go:

```
tweets = JSON.parse(response.body)

tweets.each do |tweet|
    puts tweet["text"]
end
```

**Update:**

Well, I guess the quotes within quotes won't be a problem here as long as you use string interpolation. But it's still not the preferred way. I'd rather go with `"#{tweet['text']}"`.